# Delete a value from an array of an object in an array in a Mongo DB document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Good Day and thank you for taking your time with my question!

I am in the process of learning how to code and this is my first question here:

I have a MongoDB collection that is structured like the following example. Each document is representating a period, for which users gave availabilities.

```
{
    "_id": id,
    "period": 20218,
    "availabilities": [{
        "User": id1,
        "Username": "Cool Guy",
        "Useravailabilities": [9, 13, 14, 28, 29]
    }, {
        "User": id2,
        "Username": "Nice Guy",
        "Useravailabilities": [1, 2, 13, 29, 30]
    }],
}
```

```
{
    "_id": id,
    "period": 20219,
    "availabilities": [...],
}
```

```
{
    "_id": id,
    "period": 202110,
    "availabilities": [...],
}
```

I get a period (e.g. 20218), a User-ID (e.g. id2) and a day (e.g. 13), that should be removed from the corresponding Useravailabilities array. This query does not do the job, can anybody please help?

`DB.updateOne({"period": 20218, "availabilities.User": id2  }, {$pull : {"availabilities.$.Useravailabilities": 13}} )`

Thank you in advance and enjoy your day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DB.updateOne(
    { period: 20218 },
    { $pull: { 'availabilities.$[elem].Useravailabilities': 13 } },
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.User': id2 }] }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now i get: 

`Error: Could not find path "undefined.0.User" in schema at castArrayFilters`

Maybe it has something to do with my schema?

`new mongoose.Schema({
    period: Number,
    availabilities: []
  })`

Comment: Excuse me, I had written the code incorrectly. I just changed you can try again.